# IE SCRIPT16389 Error with Flash ExternalInterface Callback and JQuery Slider

Tags: php, javascript, flash, internet-explorer

I'm having a really odd issue with Internet Explorer, on my website I'm using the JQuery AnythingSlider plugin to display some videos. Whenever someone slides to the next video, I have a flash call back:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
ExternalInterface.addCallback("movie_pause",player.pause);
```

and:

```
var obj = swfobject.getObjectById($(this).attr('id'));
if(obj){
    obj.movie_pause(); //This is where the error takes place
}
```

Now the weird thing is, when the page is first loaded, everything runs fine. However after a refresh, or just randomly after sliding a couple of times, IE starts throwing error SCRIPT16389: Unspecified Error and points to the above line. But if I am debugging with IE, it instead points to:

```
function __flash_addCallback(instance, name) {
    instance[name] = function() {
        return eval(instance.CallFunction("<invoke name=\""+name+"\" returntype=\"javascript\">" + __flash__argumentsToXML(arguments,0) + "</invoke>"));
    }
}
```

I'm embedding my videos using swfObject:

```
<object id="testimonial_{testimonials_ID}" 
    classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="720" height="480">
    <param name="movie" value="<?php echo content_url();?>videos/player/agflvplayer.swf">
    <param name=FlashVars value="id=testimonial_{testimonials_ID}&flvurl=<?php 
    echo content_url();?>{testimonials_url}&player_skin=<?php 
    echo content_url();?>videos/player/SkinOverAllNoCaption.swf&volume=0">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="<?php echo content_url();?>videos/player/agflvplayer.swf" width="720" height="480">
        <param name=FlashVars value="id=testimonial_{testimonials_ID}&flvurl=<?php 
        echo content_url();?>{testimonials_url}&player_skin=<?php 
        echo content_url();?>videos/player/SkinOverAllNoCaption.swf&volume=0">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <p>Alternative content</p>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

You can take a look at the issue http://people.oregonstate.edu/~egliju/agtools/welcome/test/'>http://people.oregonstate.edu/~egliju/agtools/welcome/test.
Nearest issue I could find is [ExternalInterface not working in IE after page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133512/externalinterface-not-working-in-ie-after-page-refresh) but there is no answer(they just recommend using swfobject, which I am).

Comment: Please contact the vendor of the browser in case you can't get any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, it seems I've figured out a way around the issue. It seems it has to due with Internet Explorer caching the flash player and for some reason, that causes problems. So I tricked it into reloading itself every time by changing the movie param url to something different for every player.

```
<param name="movie" value="player/player.swf?no_cache=<?php echo rand();?>">
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this.  I have applied the same logic with javascript  using Math.random()  and it has just ended an 8 hour battle with Internet Explorer. I know people have had this issue, why has nobody stumbled on this answer yet?

Comment: And for the record I'm using swfObject's dynamic embedding and had the same problem/solution.  Too bad I can't upvote more than once

Comment: I had a similar problem with a flash piece in a jquery dialog with "show: slide".  With that, in ie, can't call methods on flash object.  Was also using swfobject.  killing the transition solved it.  IE has some serious weirdness here.