# PLupload fails on secondary tries to add a file in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, wordpress, plupload

I am using plupload within a WordPress plugin to handle uploading images to products in my online store. It's all working fine except in IE8, and possibly some other versions older than 11.

Using IE8 Developer Tools I was able to pinpoint the error to this code:

```
function __flash__addCallback(instance, name) {
  instance[name] = function () {
    return eval(instance.CallFunction(“” + __flash__argumentsToXML(arguments,0) + “”));
  }
}
```

which I gather means there is some problem between Flash and javascript communicating with each other. After googling the issue some possible causes include:
1. Naming swf calls using reserved words such as play, stop, pause, etc. I don't think that's the case here.
2. CSS rules hiding the container that plupload is trying to make calls on. I don't think that's my problem either but have not ruled it out conclusively.
3. The plupload object not being instantiated or cleaned up properly. I think this is where the bug may lie but am not sure how to confirm this or fix it.

The url where you can see the problem is http://mpp.jebwebsolutions.com.au/product/a5-custom-jigsaw-puzzle/. Using IE8, try uploading a photo, adding it to the cart, continue shopping, then uploading another photo. Flash needs to be installed, and is on my test environment.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After much frustration I thikn I have finally managed to solve this issue. I found the clue that helped me at [IE SCRIPT16389 Error with Flash ExternalInterface Callback and JQuery Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698543/ie-script16389-error-with-flash-externalinterface-callback-and-jquery-slider).

All I ended up doing is adding a 'no_cache' query parameter to the .swf file which loads the Flash functionality to prevent IE from caching it (other browsers mainly use the HTML5 runtime) like this:

```
flash_swf_url       : '<?php echo $this -> plugin_meta['url']?>/js/uploader/Moxie.swf?no_cache=<?php echo rand();?>',
```

and now it is working consistently in IE8! :)