# SCRIPT 16389 error occur when calling flash externalInterface callback

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, flash, swfobject, externalinterface

I'm making a recording functionality of a webpage using SWFObject.js. When the start-recording button and stop-recording button is clicked each will invoke the `startRecording()` and `stopRecording()` function.

When my Javascript trying to invoke the ExternalInterface Callback, `record()` and `stop()`, IE browser is throwing a SCRIPT 16389 error. In other browsers the ExternalInterface Callback works just fine.

```
function startRecording() {
    var myFlashMovie = document.getElementById("ie_video_recorder");
    myFlashMovie.connect();
    myFlashMovie.record();
}

function stopRecording() {
    var myFlashMovie = document.getElementById("ie_video_recorder");
    myFlashMovie.stop();
    recordButton.disabled=true;
}
```

Is there anyone had the same problem before and know how to fix it?

Comment: Show code of the element with id of `ie_video_recorder`. Use the [`edit`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57262887/edit) button to add.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of SWFObject version are you using? Please note, from 2015 the SWFObject is no longer in active development. According to the [SWFObject Github document](https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject), I have tried to create a sample, but not successful, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Besides, according to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698543/ie-script16389-error-with-flash-externalinterface-callback-and-jquery-slider), perhaps the issue is related to the cache, I suggest you could try to clear the browser cache and history, then retest your code.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm using version 2.2 and after some testing with my colleague, we think maybe the server that the code is trying to connect is the cause of the error, but it will take some time for checking.